# jQuery function - unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery

**[Please see my demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/DmFmM/)**

What it does:

- once selected tab on the top it is getting its class  and show only `ul.portfolio > li`
  elements with this class

  ```
     $('.portfolio-filter li a').click(function() {


      $('.portfolio-filter > .selected').prop('class','');
      $(this).parent('li').addClass('selected');

      var FilterClass = $(this).attr('class');

      $('#portfolio-items li').hide();
      $('#portfolio-items li.' + FilterClass).show();
      $('#portfolio-items').CreateTabs();

  });
  ```
- then run CreateTabs function - which creates pagination at the bottom
- problem is that the last element which is **`<li class="all website"></li>` has not got `'logo'` class on it**, but if you select tab LOGO it will get displayed./

**Why? Any suggestions much appreciated!**

Comment: Your pagination code displays all the links, not just the links of the selected tab. Because the logo is the only tab that has more than 4 items, you don't see it in the other tabs.

Comment: @Pelshoff - I don't understand - can you try once again explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `CreateTabs` and `Pagination` functions.

Here's the solution for `CreateTabs`:

```
$.fn.CreateTabs = function(filterClass){

        var CoundNumberOfDivs = $('#portfolio-items li:visible').length;
        $('.pagination li a').hide();
        if( CoundNumberOfDivs <= 4 ) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            var num = Math.ceil(CoundNumberOfDivs / 4);
            $('.pagination li a:lt(' + num + ')').show();
            $('#portfolio-items li').hide();
            if (filterClass === undefined) {
                $('#portfolio-items li:lt(4)').show();
            } else {
                $('#portfolio-items li.' + filterClass + ':lt(4)').show();
            }
        }

    };
})(jQuery);
```

If you remove the `logo` class on one of the first four elements, you will see that the filter works.
Now, the pagination will still make the problems... So here's a solution.

```
var filterClass;

$('.portfolio-filter li a').click(function() {


    $('.portfolio-filter > .selected').prop('class','');
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('selected');

    filterClass = $(this).attr('class');

    $('#portfolio-items li').hide();
    $('#portfolio-items li.' + filterClass).show();
    $('#portfolio-items').CreateTabs(filterClass);

});

$('ul.pagination li a').click(function(event) {
        $('ul.pagination li .active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

    var PI = $('#portfolio-items li' + (filterClass !== undefined) ? '.' + filterClass : '');
        $('#portfolio-items li').hide();
    .....
```

The part with

```
        if ($(this).hasClass('href-1')) {
            PI.slice(0, 4).show();
        }
        .... etc
```

Has to be rewritten - frankly, this is just bad.

Comment: sorry, I can't your code to work. Did you made a fiddle with working example?

Comment: got that working know http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/DmFmM/47/ - why onload nothing is seleted - shouldn't  yours `if (filterClass === undefined)` deal with it?

Comment: To get the default selection - replace the part:
`$(document).ready(function() {
    var filterClass = 'all';
    $('#portfolio-items li').CreateTabs(filterClass);`

Answer (score 0):

I didnt understand completely, but I think that the problem is in your pagination function, because last LI element is displayed only if you switch to 3rd page, am I right? 
Look at this: 
-Click All
-Click 3rd page
-Click "Logo"
-Observe
-Result: The number 3 continues selected, and the pagination order is changed, if you click page 2, the results are higher than the ones in page 3.

Comment: I don't understand - can you try once again explain?